# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.pro.mychatapp.Friends

Tags: java, android, firebase, chat

**Log**
this is what i get

I am facing the following error com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.pro.mychatapp.Friends
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:22)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ObservableSnapshotArray.getObject(ObservableSnapshotArray.java:141)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.CachingObservableSnapshotArray.getObject(CachingObservableSnapshotArray.java:40)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:127)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:164)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
```

**FirendsFragment.java**

i just want to display list of friends

```
package com.example.pro.mychatapp;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView myFriendsList;

    private DatabaseReference FriendsReference;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    String online_user_id;

    private View myMainView;

    public FriendsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        myMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);


        myFriendsList = (RecyclerView) myMainView.findViewById(R.id.friends_list);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance() ;
        online_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        FriendsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(online_user_id);


        myFriendsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return myMainView;


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder > firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder>
                        (
                                Friends.class,
                                R.layout.all_users_display_layout,
                                FriendsViewHolder.class,
                                FriendsReference

                         )
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(FriendsViewHolder viewHolder, Friends model, int position)
                    {
                        System.out.println("********************************************************************");

                        viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());

                    }
                };

        myFriendsList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    public static class FriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        View mView;


        public FriendsViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            mView =itemView;
        }

        public void setDate(String date)
        {
            TextView sinceFriendsDate = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_status);
            sinceFriendsDate.setText(date);
        }
    }
}
```

**Friends.java**

```
package com.example.pro.mychatapp;



public class Friends {
    public  String date;



    public Friends()
    {

    }
    public Friends(String date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

May i know what is the problem? I am new to firebase and i need your help. I read some similar question here but i still can't solve my problem. Can any expert here help me?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the JSON at `FriendsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(online_user_id);` to your question (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please add your database structure as Frank asked you.

Comment: you guys thanks, i got the problem in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things could be happening here from what I can see.

1.) Your data for the "date" property on the Friends model could not match up the naming convention when parsing your datasnapshot --> object. I cannot see an example of your object in the database, so just needed to clarify that.

2.) This line of code seems to be retrieving a single child object which is a key and not the Friend object.

```
FriendsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(online_user_id);
```

Instead, I assume you would want to use [FirebaseListOptions](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-listview) and populate with a query specifying the user's friends.

3.) Here is a fine [example](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/data-persistence/firebase-recycleradapter.) of a basic case that you are trying to perform,
I would definitely use that as a reference.

Based on the error

Comment: thanks, now it workes the problem was in the database.

Comment: @fasil cool. Any chance I can get the answer marked as the right one? Thanks.